# Need help translating Curl statement to Powershell

Tags: powershell, curl

I'm trying to rewrite the following curl code: (note I've used OBSCURED to conceal secrets)

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
     -H "Authorization: Bearer OBSCURED" \
     -X POST \
     -d "{\"color\": \"pink\", \"message\": \"OBSCURED\" }" \
     https://OBSCURED
```

into something I can use in Powershell but I'm running into a lot of grief.. this is my attempt so far:

```
$body = @{
color = "pink"
message = "OBSCURED"
}

Invoke-WebRequest -ContentType application/json -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer OBSCURED"} -Method Post -Body "$body" -Uri https://OBSCURED
```

But I'm running into this powershell error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.At E:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell2561816976397359486.ps1:16 char:1
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer OBSCURED ...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test this now, but I believe you need to submit JSON as body, so you might try converting your body to JSON first with convertto-JSON and then try posting:

`$bodyJSON = body |convertto-JSON`

then call:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -ContentType application/json -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer OBSCURED"} -Method Post -Body $bodyJSON -Uri https://OBSCURED
```

Comment: thanks! that was what needed.. lol I should have been able to think of that one on my own